# reverse lexicographic order after using expand.grid

Tags: r, permutation

I'm trying to generate the following matrix, based on a multinomial framework.  For example, if I had three columns, I'd get:

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
```

But, I want many more columns.  I know I can use expand.grid, like:

```
u <- list(0:1)
expand.grid(rep(u,3))
```

But, it returns what I want in the wrong order:

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
1 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can reorder your rows to match your expected output:

```
u <- list(0:1)
g <- expand.grid(rep(u,3))
g <- g[order(rowSums(g)), ]
```